# Static template field of template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I've got this code to port from windows to linux.

```
template<class T, int Size> 
class CVector {
 /* ... */
};

template<int n, int m>
class CTestClass {
public:
 enum { Size = 1 << n };
private:
 static CVector<int, Size> a; // main.cpp:19
};

template<int n, int m>
CVector<int, CTestClass<n, m>::Size> CTestClass<n, m>::a; // main.cpp:24
```

It compiles with VS2008, but doesn't with g++ 4.3.2.
The error I receive is:

> main.cpp:24: error: conflicting
>   declaration ‘CVector CTestClass::alpha_to’
>
> main.cpp:19: error: ‘CTestClass< n,
>   m >::alpha_to’ has a previous
>   declaration as ‘CVector< int,
>   CTestClass< n, m >::Size > CTestClass< n,
>   m >::alpha_to’
>
> main.cpp:24: error: declaration of
>   ‘CVector< int, CTestClass< n, m >::Size >
>   CTestClass< n, m >::alpha_to’ outside of
>   class is not definition

Does someone know how to make it compilable via g++?

Thanks!

Comment: I think its another MSVC++ extension although I am not sure. Someone please throw some light over it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works with gcc 3.4 & 4.3 as well as VC8:

```
template<class T, int Size> 
class CVector {
 /* ... */
};

template<int n, int m>
class CTestClass {
public:
    enum { Size = 1 << n };
    typedef CVector<int, Size> Vector;
private:
    static Vector a; 
};

template<int n, int m>
typename CTestClass<n,m>::Vector CTestClass<n,m>::a;
```

Comment: Seems to be solution to the problem.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Actually CTestClass::a does depends on template parameter 'n'. Look carefully to the code.

> why not use std::vector instead of CVector?

It's not my code, but suppose there were some reasons. And in fact it doesn't matters - code won't compile with `std::vector` either.

Comment: You are right.  Sorry, I missed it.  But try taking out the declaration on line 24.  I've just tried it, and it compiles with g++ on cygwin.

Comment: And does functionality of this code will be saved in this case?

Comment: Yeah there wont be any problem at the time of compilation(if he deletes that line) but his program wont link then.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with enum.

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#enum[link text](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#enum)

Comment: I had a similar thought, but I changed size to a const int and still got the same error as the asker (at least on g++ 4.1.2)

Answer (score -1):

If you take out the declaration of `a` outside the class, it compiles on cygwin with g++ v. 3.4.4.

By the way, why not use `std::vector` instead of `CVector`?

Comment: No I dont understand why he doesn't even need to initialize the static member. Could you explain a bit?

Comment: He is not initializing it, because he is not giving it any value.  He is just declaring it.

Comment: Actually CTestClass::a does depends on template parameter 'n'. Look carefully to the code.

why not use std::vector instead of CVector?

It's not my code, but suppose there were some reasons. And in fact it doesn't matters - code won't compile with std::vector either.

Comment: How to delete an answer? I've posted text to answer instead of comment, now wont to delete answer.

Answer (score -1):

In CTestClass, Size is an enum and not an int (by standard it's implementation dependant, enum doesnt have to be an integer). Try using a static const int Size = ...